# Refreshing a question with a changed title doesn't readjust title height

Tags: bug, android-app, title

Observed consistently on Android App v1.0.35 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2:

1. Open a question with a single-line title, in both the App and in your desktop browser
2. Edit the question in the desktop browser. Make the title longer, so that it will span at least a second line in the App's question view.
3. Refresh the question in the App. The new title will be loaded correctly However, the area where the title is displayed will still only be high enough to contain a single line, so the question title will get cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the same bug now in version **1.0.43**, I guess it makes sense to bump the report with brand new screenshots. They are from Galaxy S3 running 4.4.2. This is what happened when I changed a question title from "Notation used in a book" to a longer one.

#### In the app (even after refresh)

[image: app]

It seems that not just the height but also the width is taken from the old title. The word "book" would definitely fit on the same line, but it got cut off nonetheless.

#### In a browser:

[image: browser]

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: the title height is readjusted every time the Q&A thread is refreshed (e.g. after edits, etc.)

Before edit: "*Android strange icons*"

[image: short title]

After edit from external & refresh: "*Strange icons artefact on app launcher on QMobile Noir LT250 running Android KitKat*"

[image: long title]